# How to minimize data space used? (redeclaring a 2D array in a function)

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, embedded

I am working on several different LED Tower animations. Current approach is to initialize a 2D array with certain values and copy them to a global 2D array which is used to update the display. However, each function containing a 2D unsigned char array of [15][4] bytes takes up a lot of data space. I would like to ask what is the appropriate way to redeclare a global array from the function without having to initialize a new one per each animation.

```
const int BYTES     = 4;    // bytes per layer
const int LAYERS    = 15;   // height of the tower

unsigned char LED_Buffer[15][4] = {0}; // global array


void someFunc(void){

    unsigned char buffer[15][4] = 
{
0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c,
0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60,
0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0,
0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18,
0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03
};

    for (int y = 0; y < LAYERS; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < BYTES; x++)
            {
                LED_Buffer[y][x] = buffer[y][x];
            }
        }
// animation code
// ...
}
```

Comment: Is this array same for all of the functions? Then define it as global `static const`. But if it is local in functions, you should not worry about the *cumulative* space, as only one will be allocated per call.

Comment: You can also use `memcpy()` to copy the array in one step, rather than a loop.

Comment: You can declare it as a local static array. The memory will then be global, and it will be initialized once, not every time the function is called.

Comment: @Barmar But that would actually increase the memory usage as there will be a statically allocated array per function

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not really. The initial value for each function's array has to be stored somewhere so it can be copied into the stack. This just uses that as the actual array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If i define it as static const I can no longer modify it.

Comment: @RytisBe You didn't tell us that you want to modify it

Comment: @Barmar  Oh, I see what you mean. The initializer is using up the space as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it `static`. The memory will be in the process's data section, and it will be initialized when the program starts up, not every time the function is called.

```
void someFunc(void){

    static const unsigned char buffer[15][4] = 
    {
    0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c,
    0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60,
    0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0,
    0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x60, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18,
    0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03
    };

    memcpy(LED_buffer, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
// animation code
// ...
}
```

Comment: With `const` you may have moved it into the (read-only) rodata section in ROM.  Even better.